# Bootstrap well sizing based on content

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap wells to represent meals that can be ordered by customers. When meal title is too long it creates wells of different sizes. Is there way how to say "Take the proportions of biggest well in this area and make others as big as this one is". I am looking for some non painful way already implemented in bootstrap if possible.

[image: Different well sizes]

Comment: You're essentially asking for _equal height columns_ in Bootstrap, which has been asked before. Beyond that it looks like you'll have to position your numbers and order button to the bottom of said columns.

Comment: Please ask only one clearly-defined question per post. Your question about emphasizing text should be posted separately.

Comment: @hungerstar Ok that looks good. I think I'll give it a try. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to do this built right into bootstrap 3, but I have used this jquery plugin to match heights. https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height.

Flexbox could also be another option for you as it has great browser support now.

Comment: In Bootstrap 4, you'd use a [card group](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/#card-groups) or  [card deck](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/#card-decks) to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap 3, the best way to do this is by JS. Below is a jQuery equalize function that is pretty easy to use. To use the code below, you would simply add the class "equalize" to each item whose height you want to evenly set. Then in the parent div of all those "equalize" classes, give the parent a class of "equalized-group". Codepen example below:

https://codepen.io/ymeiner/pen/NdKPLj

```
equalize = function() {
  $('.equalized-group').each(function() {
    var maxHeight = 0;
    $(this).find('.equalized').height('auto');
    $(this).find('.equalized').each(function() {
      if (maxHeight < $(this).height()) maxHeight = $(this).height();
    });
    $(this).find('.equalized').each(function() {
      $(this).height(maxHeight);
    });
  });
}
$(window).resize(function() {
  equalize();
});
$(window).load(function() {
  equalize();
});
```